# Is it possible to get the matched string after calling :search()?

Tags: vimscript, search

In a vimscript-function, I need to assign a matched string to a variable `l:matched` after calling `search()` and I am wondering if there is a shorter way than what I am currently doing:

```
let l:pattern   = '\v^Foo: \zs.*'
let l:line      = search(l:pattern)
let l:line_text = getline(l:line)
let l:matched   = matchstr(l:line, l:pattern)
```

Ideally, I'd want something like

```
let l:matched = search_text(l:pattern)
```

without resorting to `getline()`. Is there such a vim function that I seem unable to find?

Comment: Sadly, the answer is no.

Comment: protip: local variables are the default inside of functions so you can probably forgo the `l:` namespace declaration.

Comment: in a function you can probably do: `:let @/="pattern" | norm! ygn` and have the content in register 0 available.

Answer (score 8):

Since the cursor is placed on the 1st letter of the match, you could probably do a `:normal! y$` after the search, and get the register content in your local variable.

Another approach, which I think would work here very well, would be to use `:substitute` with the `n` flag (i.e. without an *actual* substitution):

```
function! ActOn(match)
    " do something with the match
    echo a:match
    " [...]
endfunction

function! FindAndCall(regex, func_name)
    execute ':keeppatterns %s/' . a:regex . '/\=' . a:func_name. '(submatch(0))/gn'
endfunction
```

... and which you call like this:

```
:call FindAndCall('^Foo: \zs.*', 'ActOn')
```

This practically makes `ActOn` a callback function - it will be evaluated for each match.

Comment: Note: `:s` with a sub-replace-expression and the `n` flag is only available since Vim 7.3.627+. Otherwise you need to do an actually substitution (lame as this will mark the buffer as modified). You probably also want to save and restore the search register, `@/`, or use `:keeppatterns`.

Comment: Please fix the typo: `keeppaterns` -> `keeppatterns`. It is causing `E488: Trailing characters` which is rather tricky to trace back to the cause. Thanks!